# Accessing VPC peering connection from another VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering

I have a structure similar to below:

[image: Two VPCs connected using VPC peering]

Two VPCs connected using VPC peering. Is it possible I add a third VPC(**VPC C**) to reach the VPC A, through the VPC B, without doing a peering connection between VPC A and VPC C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. VPC Peering is **not transitive**.

It is not possible to 'transit' one VPC while moving between two VPCs.

If you are wanting to interconnect multiple VPCs, you could consider using an [AWS Transit Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/transit-gateway-centralized-router.html).

[image: AWS Transit Gateway]